# remindd: constant 100% CPU load on my two Macs

Tags: macos, icloud, reminders

The remindd service on my two Macs runs at a constant 100% CPU load. Having a look at the console, two errors are reported over and over again (strangely with one emoji being differently every time):

`REMAlarmCDIngestor: cdAlarm.trigger is nil {cdAlarm.remObjectID: ~<x-apple-reminderkit://REMCDAlarm/E96CEE35-7E87-4ECD-A912-D080C6AD90E7>}`

`Error occured when mapping object from <private> to <private> {error: <private>}`

Somehow, this appears to be related to my iCloud reminders – I have tried turning off the iCloud reminder sync, which — after a reboot – stops this madness. As soon as I turn it back on again, it continues. This error occurred on my recent MBP, now continues to occur on my new MBA, and also occurs on my iMac, which leads me to believe that something is amiss with my centrally stored reminders. Any idea, what could be done here? Thanks!